# Changing filling of some node in tikzpicture using \matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, nodes

I have used the handy `\matrix` trick in a `tikzpicture` (see code) to build up a graph. Now I wanted to change the filling of one node. I can't find out how! Of course, I can find out, how to change fillings, but not in combination with the `\matrix` environment. I hope, someone here can give me a hint :)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, column sep = {1 cm}, row sep = {1cm}, nodes ={circle, fill = lightgray, draw, anchor = center}, ampersand replacement =\&]
{ 
|(A)| A \& |(B)| B \& |(F)| F \\
|(C)| C \&        \& |(G)| G \\
|(D)| D \& |(E)| B \& |(H)| H \\
};
\tikzstyle{every node}=[color=blue]
\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw (B) -- (F);
\draw (F) -- (G);
\draw (G) -- (H);
\draw (E) -- (H);
\draw (D) -- (E);
\draw (A) -- (C);
\draw (C) -- (D);
\draw (C) -- (B);
\draw (C) -- (E);
\draw (B) -- (E);
\draw (B) -- (G);
\draw (G) -- (E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image: The graph]

Comment: Substitute, for example, `|(E)| B` with `|(E) [rectangle,draw,fill=red]| B`. What you have specified in `nodes={...}` is just the default style of nodes, use `|...|` to adjust single nodes. Note that `...` can be whatever of the TikZ `\node` syntax, except `\node` and `node` (the text of the node can be written outside).

Comment: perfect!!! That's exactly I was hoping for.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @PierPaolo I think you should turn your comment into a proper answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Wrote an answer and added a few remarks. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>As @Gonzalo Medina suggested, I turned my comment into an answer.</sup>

When you setup a matrix in Tikz and use `nodes={...}` as an option for the matrix itself, you specify the *default* behavior of the nodes. If you want to change the appearance of a single node, just put your specifications inside two vertical bars `|...|`: this notation accepts the specifications you would usually pass to an “usual” node (except for `\node` and `node`.

So, for example, if you wanted to change the appearance of node `(A)` you could do it with:

```
|(A) [rectangle,draw,fill=red]| A
```

instead of `|(A)| A`.

Here is the full code (with additions explained later):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (M) [matrix of nodes, column sep = {1 cm}, row sep = {1cm}, nodes ={circle, fill = lightgray, draw, anchor = center}, ampersand replacement =\&]
    { 
      |(A) [rectangle,draw,fill=red]| A \& |(B)| B \& |(F)| F \\
      |(C)| C \&        \& |(G)| G \\
      |(D)| D \& |(E)| B \& |(H)| H \\
    };
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[color=blue]
    \draw (A) -- (B)
    (B) -- (F)
    (F) -- (G)
    (G) -- (H)
    (E) -- (H)
    (D) -- (E)
    (A) -- (C)
    (C) -- (D)
    (C) -- (B)
    (C) -- (E)
    (B) -- (E)
    (B) -- (G)
    (G) -- (E);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Remark #1

You can avoid all those `\draw` commands and just write:

```
\draw (A) -- (B)
      (B) -- (F)
      (F) -- (G)
      (G) -- (H)
      (E) -- (H)
      (D) -- (E)
      (A) -- (C)
      (C) -- (D)
      (C) -- (B)
      (C) -- (E)
      (B) -- (E)
      (B) -- (G)
      (G) -- (E);
```

#### Remark #2

You can avoid naming manually each and every node of the matrix itself: You can name your matrix, say `(M)`

```
\matrix (M) [...] {...}; % a matrix is a node itself
```

and then access every node with

```
(M-i-j)
```

where `i` is the i-th row and `j` is the j-th column of the matrix. The draw commands would then be rewritten as:

```
\draw (M-1-1) -- (M-1-2)
      (M-1-2) -- (M-1-3)
      ... ;
```

This helps you for complex matrices and enables the use of a `\foreach` loop. (As a side note, for graphs like the one you posted, this may just be a complication: better stick with nodes named after their (simple) text content.)

*Note:* These methods of accessing the nodes are not compatible, i.e. you can't write:

```
\draw (A) -- (B)           % this WON'T work!!!
      (M-1-2) -- (M-1-3);  % :(
```